# Opensource / free iOS Enterprise store

Tags: android, iphone, ios, xcode, enterprise

Is there any opensource / free (that you can install and modify on your server) enterprise apps distribution server solution. I know about plenty (test flight, nukona, etc ...) but we can't use them as they are someone else's solution.

It would be great it this would support other platforms like Android or WP7 ...

Comment: There is no such thing for plain iOS devices and Apple would not approve it anyways. So the only workaround would be using jailbroken devices.

Comment: There is, please take a look (Google) at Apple enterprise program ... we are using it for quite a while already and it doesn't go through the Apple approval process ... what I am looking for is a distribution solution that you have to write yourself ...

Comment: Apple's Enterprise program is only for in-house distribution. If that is what you were aiming for, then I got your question wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is for an in-house distribution ... we are an app development agency and that's all we do ... we can't do websites otherwise we would built that enterprise store already ... :(

Comment: Hockey works pretty well for us - though occasionally it fails installing apps on certain devices, forcing us  to use either the iPhone Configuration Utility or iTunes.

Comment: @Till ... that is one of the reasons why i would like to have our own solution on our servers ...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Installing apps wirelessly](https://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/?lang=en-us#app43ad871e) from Apple's iOS Developer Library.

I dont know about Android or WP7 though.

Comment: I know about that, I am looking for a solution that would work straight away ... something like an opensource testflight, nukona or hockeyapp